# Bubble sorting messing up string values?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a file of lines of data with the form:

```
NAME,SUBJECT
```

I put all these lines into an array of structures defined as:

```
struct node{
char name[10];
char subject[15];
};
```

using the following code:

```
    i = 0;
    fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL) /* let's populate our structures with the data files */
    {
            token = strtok(buffer, del);
            strcpy(data[i].name, token);
            token = strtok(NULL, del);
            strcpy(data[i].subject, token);
            i++;
    }
    cols = i;
```

where data is an array of structures defined by:

```
struct node data[25];
```

and del is:

```
char* del = ',\n';
```

I called sortData(data, cols); which has the definition:

```
void sortData(struct node data[], int cols)
{
    int i, unsorted;
    struct node temp;

do {
    unsorted = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < cols-1; i++)
        if( strcmp(data[i].name, data[i+1].name) > 0 )
        {
            temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i+1];
            data[i+1] = temp;
            unsorted = 1;
        }

} while(unsorted);
}
```

However, after calling it, it seems to have messed up the string values for the subject? Here is a before sort version of the array:

```
Name & Subject at index 0 is Brian and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 1 is Tanbir and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 2 is Summit and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 3 is Adam and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 4 is Dominic and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 5 is Zackery and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 6 is Nicholas and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 7 is Julianne and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 8 is Ana and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 9 is Daniel and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 10 is Amarachi and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 11 is Thamid and MATH 1426
Name & Subject at index 12 is Khoa and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 13 is Danny and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 14 is Alejandro and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 15 is Damian and MATH 1426
Name & Subject at index 16 is Dwij and MATH 1426
Name & Subject at index 17 is Michelle and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 18 is Grace and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 19 is Paul and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 20 is Hiba and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 21 is Hari and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 22 is Elizabeth and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 23 is Keenan and IE 3301
```

and after calling the sortData function:

```
Name & Subject at index 0 is Adam and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 1 is Alejandro and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 2 is Amarachi and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 3 is Ana and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 4 is Brian and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 5 is Damian and MATH 1426Daniel
Name & Subject at index 6 is Daniel and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 7 is Danny and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 8 is Dominic and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 9 is Dwij and MATH 1426Elizabeth
Name & Subject at index 10 is Elizabeth and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 11 is Grace and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 12 is Hari and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 13 is Hiba and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 14 is Julianne and CSE 1310
Name & Subject at index 15 is Keenan and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 16 is Khoa and CSE 1320
Name & Subject at index 17 is Michelle and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 18 is Nicholas and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 19 is Paul and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 20 is Summit and IE 3301
Name & Subject at index 21 is Tanbir and CSE 2315
Name & Subject at index 22 is Thamid and MATH 1426Zackery
Name & Subject at index 23 is Zackery and IE 3301
```

why do some of the names mess up and stick to the subjects?

Comment: How does your bubble sort ignore the last "bubbled" item on subsequent passes (somewhat the entire point of a bubble-sort)? Each pass should reduce your `cols` by one, and yours doesn't appear to do that? Regardless, this is wrong : `char* del = ',\n';`, and your compiler should be at-least-warning you about a multi-char literal and an incompatible typed assignment. You're *sure* those are *not* double-quotes in your *real* source?

Comment: Just do one line `unsorted = 1;` before or after this `i--`, then try things

Comment: The problem with the names only occurr for subject = "MATH XXXX", which is the longest subject, though your buffer seems large enough. Can I see the printf statemen? You could try replacing the compiler struct assignment with strncpy.